# RFC compliant TCP/IP socket library/implementation to be used over raw socket

Tags: linux, open-source, networking

I want to create a system for **fast packet processing** on rhel 7.1, but kernel version does not enable solutions like kernel-bypass networking. Since I am not allowed to upgrade kernel because of security certificate issues, it seems that best option is using raw sockets. I do not want to implement handshake,congestion window, ack-seq tracking etc.

Do you have any library/framework suggestions for the specified purposes?

Comment: Any programming language will have libraries to manipulate raw sockets. But then if you want to do TCP/IP you have to implement everything yourself. On command line you have this powerful tool: http://secdev.org/projects/scapy/